# ARM assembly Printing binary number using a loop without any zeros

Tags: assembly, arm

I've recently got into trying ARM assembly language (my first assembly language) and was trying to print out a binary number using a loop. 
This is the code I'm currently using:

```
        .global _start              @ Provide program starting address to linker
_start: mov         R0,#0b101101    @ An arbitrary sample of binary value for testing
        bl          v_bin           @ Call subroutine to view binary value of R0 to ASCII.
        mov         R0,#0           @ Exit Status code set to 0 indicates "normal completion"
        mov         R7,#1           @ Service command code (1) will terminate this program
        svc         0               @ Issue Linux command to terminate program
@           Subroutine v_bin will display a 32-bit register binary digits
@                   R0: contains a number to be displayed in binary
@                   R2: Number of bits to be displayed (from right side of R0)
@                   LR: Contains the return address
v_bin:  push        {R0-R7}         @ Save contents of registers R0 through R7
        sub         R6,R2,#1        @ Number of bits to display (-1)
        cmp         R6,#31          @ Test error value entered (bit 31 is leftmost bit)
        movhi       R6,#0           @ If bad range, default to displaying only 1 bit
        mov         R3,R0           @ R3 will hold a copy of input word to be displayed
        mov         R4,#1           @ Used to mask off 1 bit at a time for display
        ldr         R5,=dig         @ Pointer to the "01" string of ASCII characters.
        mov         R2,#1           @ Number of characters to be displayed at a time.
        mov         R0,#1           @ Code for stdout
        mov         R7,#4           @ Linux service command code to write string.
@Loop through single bits and output each to the standard output (stdout) display.
nxtbit: and         R1,R4,R3,LSR R6 @ Select next 0 or 1 to be displayed.
        add         R1,R5           @ Set R1 pointing to "0" or "1" in memory.
        svc         0               @ Linux service call code to write string.
        subs        R6,#1           @ Decrement number of bits remaining to display.
        bge         nxtbit          @ Go display next bit until all 32 displayed
        pop         {R0-R7}         @ Restore saved register contents
        bx          LR              @ Return to the calling program
        .data
dig:    .ascii      "01"            @ASCII string of binary digits 0 and 1
        .end
```

The comments are what I think should happen based on what I've read and the examples I've seen. I've tried debugging it and it seems it only runs the loop once and or returns the last 1 of the binary number given.
EDIT:
The way to fix only `1` showing up is chaniging `cmp R6,#31` to `mov R6, #31`

Only thing that is left to figure out is the removal of the 0 at the beginning and the addition of #0b at the start.
EDIT #2: The complete code that does what I set out it to do. It will remove all the extra 0s and type 0b before the binary number.

```
        .global _start              @ Provide program starting address to linker
_start: mov         R0,#0b0101101   @ An arbitrary sample of binary value for testing
        bl          v_bin           @ Call subroutine to view binary value of R0 to ASCII.
        mov         R0,#0           @ Exit Status code set to 0 indicates "normal completion"
        mov         R7,#1           @ Service command code (1) will terminate this program
        svc         0               @ Issue Linux command to terminate program

@           Subroutine v_bin will dispay a 32-bit register binary digits
@                   R0: contains a number to be dispayed in binary
@                   R2: Number of bits to be dispayed (from right side of R0)
@                   LR: Contains the return address

v_bin:  push        {R0-R7}         @ Save contents of registers R0 through R7
        mov         R8,#0
        sub         R6,R2,#1        @ Number of bits to display (-1)
        mov         R6,#31          @ Test error value entered (bit 31 is leftmost bit)
        movhi       R6,#0                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           @ If bad range, default to displaying only 1 bit
        mov         R3,R0           @ R3 will hold a copy of input word to be dispayed
        mov         R4,#1           @ Used to mask off 1 bit at a time for display
        ldr         R5,=dig         @ Pointer to the "01" string of ASCII characters.
        mov         R2,#1           @ Number of characters to be displayed at a time.
        mov         R0,#1           @ Code for stdout
        mov         R7,#4           @ Linux service command code to write string.

@           Loop through single bits and output each to the standard output (stdout) display.

nxtbit: and         R1,R4,R3,LSR R6 @ Select next 0 or 1 to be dispayed.
        cmp         R8,R1
        beq         skip
        cmp         R1,#1
        mov         R8,#2
        add         R1,R5           @ Set R1 pointing to "0" or "1" in memory.
        svc         0               @ Linux service comand code to write string.
        subs        R6,#1           @ Decrement number of bits remaining to display.
        bge         nxtbit          @ Go display next bit until all 32 dispayed

        pop         {R0-R7}         @ Restore saved register contents
        bx          LR              @ Return to the calling program

skip:   subs        R6,#1
        bge         nxtbit


        .data
dig:    .ascii      "01"            @ASCII string of binary digits 0 and 1
msgtxt: .ascii      "0b"            
        .end
```

Comment: Your C++ implementation makes no sense.  Why would you not just `cout << s;` if the caller is already passing a string instead of a `uint32_t`?  Also, I think the indentation is wrong; the `else if (!t)` is actually an `else` for the `(t)` condition, so the `if()` is redundant.  But you've indented it as if it was an `else` for the `if(s[i]=='1')`, so it looks like `t` would become false on the first `1` and then stop printing.

Comment: The C++ implementation was just something I threw together very quickly to have a representation of what kind of output I want. The C++ code works fine even though it might not be efficient or good practice. The whole point of not couting s right away is because it more accurately represents how you would print something to the console in assembler in my current situation.

Comment: Its input is a string, so it's a completely different function than what you have in asm, with shift / and.  In C++, you want something like `do { cout << (x&1) + '0'; } while(x>>=1);`, except that prints in reverse order.  (So you could instead store into a `char buf[33]` starting from the end, and `cout` that).

Comment: I agree about the c++ side, but the problem is, is that the asm side doesn't work. Like I stated it only outputs a single digit "1". And having gone through all the registers with a debugger I still can't find a reason. It seems that the loop is only going off once, but I can't tell why.

Comment: `svc   0` clobbers at least `r0` (with the return value of `write`).  By coincidence, this is `1` (the length you passed) if it succeeds, which is also the system-call number for `sys_write`.  But that's a really hacky optimization to leave the `mov r0, #1` out of the loop.  Does `svc 0` clobber any other registers?

Comment: Anyway, the problem with having bogus C++ is that it makes this a bad SO question.  By far the easiest way for people to see exactly what you're *trying* to do in asm is to read the C++ code.  So it's a huge problem that it's not even close to the same algorithm, even if the output is the same.

Comment: `r6` is zero when your function runs (or hold garbage).  So your function does exactly what the comments say, and prints 1 digit.

Comment: When I checked it step by step with a debugger `r6` held `1`

Comment: So it prints bit 1 and then bit 0, right?  Try running your program under `strace` to see what system calls it makes.  Oh and BTW, my earlier comment about `r0` should have been that `r0=1` is fd 1 (for stdout); the system call number does go in `r7`.  But anyway, did you check if `svc 0` clobbers other registers, or put the `mov r0, #1` inside the loop?

Comment: `svc 0` shouldn't clobber other registers in theory. The version with `mov r0, #1` inside the loop does work. I just found a work around that did it this way and said that it was more efficient this way so I used it.

Comment: In the future call it pseudo code rather than specify a language to not spend time on tangents...maybe even make it look like pseudo code.  (if it were real code you could just compile it, and then use that).

Comment: you could also develop the assembly in chunks, write the chunk that walks thorugh the bits have it call a function, implement that function in C or C++ and link the assembly code in (As a function).  is this a system call problem or is this an algorithm problem or both (or neither) divide the problem in half, continue to divide until solved...

Comment: I fixed the problem of it not printing the entire number (see EDIT). All that is left is to work around the 0s and the #0b at the beginning.